# How is proper fee rate got on Bitcoin Cash

Tags: bitcoin-cash, fee-estimation

I'm developing wallet system trading BTC, BCH and so on.
In BTC, I'm using `estimatesmartfee` API to calculate by transaction size and `relayfee` to guarantee minimum fee and it works well.
In BCH, though most of logic is same as BTC except `estimatesmartfee`, `estimatefee` is used in BCH.
However, as increasing transaction size by input UTXOs, `sendrawtransaction` is often failed because of shortage of fee.

How should it implemented properly? What is it affected?
I guess some reasons,
If I need to use API to get proper fee rete from some sites, what is that site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minRelayTxFee` (which despite the name is a feerate) on BCH is 1000 satoshis per kilobyte or 1 satoshi per byte.

BCH has a blocksize limit of 32 MB and has generally had only a very small portion of the blockspace used. The current 7-day average is 27 kB blocksize. It rarely even peaks to 400 kB.

[image: Graph of blocksize in the past 7 days via fork.lol showing low blockspace usage of BCH] <sup>via fork.lol</sup>

Given that BCH is currently using about 0.1% of its available blockspace, there is no need to pay a higher fee rate than `minRelayTxFee`.

Hence, I would recommend not to spend more time on research, but instead simply hardcode a fee rate of 1000 satoshis/kB. If you want to play it safe, you can go with 1500 or 2000 satoshis/kB. In the unlikely case that BCH traffic picks up enough to fill blocks, software support should probably improve at that time and you'll be able to reevaluate then.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert of BCH but from what I can see from their JSON reference page such `estimatesmartfee` actually exists.

[LINK](https://www.bitcoincash.org/spec/JSON-RPC.html)

Comment: As far as I know, it's gone from latest node

Comment: Seems you are right. This repo has no more that command available: https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/blob/master/src/rpc/client.cpp#L112
You can maybe try to get such fee estimate from a real time API of BCH block explorer?